# ellipse vs circle

Tags: java, gwt, canvas

```
        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();

        canvas.setWidth("200px");
        canvas.setHeight("200px");

        RootPanel.get().add(canvas);

        Context2d context = canvas.getContext2d();
        context.setStrokeStyle("black");

        context.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);

        context.stroke();
```

Why I have ellipse instead of circle here?

Comment: It may be that the aspect ratio of your screen is not 1:1 - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Have you already confirmed that this effect of "ellipse instead of circle" isn't an artifact of the physical geometry of your monitor? I.e., did you use rect to draw a square, and with a ruler, confirmed all sides were equal? (Such as context.rect(30,30,40,40);)

Comment: @Riley [link](http://goo.gl/XLPKF)

Comment: @rskar [link](http://goo.gl/JsYpY)  I have no idea what is going on. My monitor looks good and I see everething fine.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Yikes stripes, that looks bad. On the bright side, it looks like the coordinate system is consistent. I wonder if there's some kind of coord-to-pixel mapping feature going on here. BTW, this is the Context2d.java from Google, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll also have to set the coordinate space, to make it match the **aspect ratio** of your canvas. So you can add the following lines:

```
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(200);
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(200);
```

Comment: The coordinate space doesn't default to something orthogonal?

Comment: You beat me to the punch! This would be my guess.

Comment: @DJClayworth: No, unfortunately it's not orthogonal by default.